# How to integrate $\frac{x+2}{x^2+2x+2}$ with the substitution method

Tags: calculus, integration

This is what I got so far:

$$\frac{x+2}{x^2+2x+2} = \frac{x+2}{(x+1)^2+1} = \int \frac{x}{(x+1)^2+1} + 2 \times \int \frac{1}{(x+1)^2+1}$$

I know the last integral $= \arctan(x+1) + c$, where $c$ is a constant, but I don't know how to integrate the first one, i.e $\int \frac{x}{(x+1)^2+1}$.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT: MY SOLUTION**

I split the fraction: $\frac{x+1}{x^2+2x+2} + \frac{1}{x^2+2x+2}$

$$\int \frac{x+1}{(x+1)^2+1}\;dx \implies (x+1)^2+1 = u$$

$$\implies \int\frac{(x+1)}{u} \text{ and } \frac{du}{2(x+1)}$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{u}\,du$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\ln(u)$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2+2x+2)$$

so finally the last integral $\int \frac{1}{x^2+2x+2}\,dx = \int \frac{1}{(x+1)^2+1}\,dx = \arctan(x+1)$

and now the solution = $\frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2+2x+2) + \arctan(x+1) + C$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\int\frac{x+2}{x^2+2x+2}dx=\int\frac{x+2}{(x+1)^2+1^2}dx$$

Put $x+1=\tan \theta$

---

Alternatively, put $x+2= A\frac{d(x^2+2x+2)}{dx}+B$

i.e., $x+2=A\cdot2(x+1)+B=2Ax+2A+B$

Comparing the coefficients of $x,1=2A\implies A=\frac12$

Comparing the constants, $2A+B=2\implies B=2-2A=1$

So, $$\int\frac{x+2}{x^2+2x+2}dx$$

$$=\frac12\int \frac{d(x^2+2x+2)}{dx}\cdot\frac1{x^2+2x+2} dx+\int\frac{dx}{x^2+2x+2}$$

$$=\frac12\int \frac{d(x^2+2x+2)}{x^2+2x+2}+\int \frac{dx}{(x+1)^2+1^2}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I solved it.

Comment: @Doody, nice to hear that. May I know you method?

Comment: *Sorry, I don't know the mark-up language on StackExchange for math so I will explain how I can*

I split the fraction: (x+1)/(x^2+2x+2) + 1/(x^2+2x+2)

integral of (x+1)/((x+1)^2+1) => (x+1)+1 = u
=>integral of (x+1)/u and du/2(x+1)
=1/2*integral of 1/u
=1/2*ln(u)
=1/2*ln(x^2+2x+2)

so finally the last integral 1/(x^2+2x+2) = 1/((x+1)^2+1) = tan^-1(x+1)

and now the solution = 1/2*ln(x^2+2x+2) + tan^-1(x+1) + C

Comment: @Doody, first of all, could you follow my methods? If your method is different from them, you can share your method even without LATEX. I shall impart my best effort to learn that

Comment: I edited my question. You can find my method there.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: You want one of the integrals to integrate to give a logarithmic function. Take this into account when you split up the fractions and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, I've managed to solve it.